# AttributeError: Context object has no attribute nickname?

Tags: bots

I'm making my first bot and when I start it I get the error "context object no nickname attribute" does anyone know how to request it?

Below a part of the bot....

```
from edamino import Bot, Context, logger
from edamino.objects import UserProfile

bot = Bot(email='bluver@hotmail.com', password='...', prefix="/")

@bot.event()
async def on_ready(profile: UserProfile):
    logger.info(f'{"bluver"} ha sido encendido')

@bot.command('ping', prefix="!")
async def on_ping(ctx: Context):
    await ctx.reply("pong")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Ready, I have added the full version of the bot

Comment: And the full traceback error?